# How to use a map() function to show a list of elements in React with Redux Saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I was trying to use React with Redux Saga.

The code that I use can be found here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-saga-stoic-euler-cjhgx-forked-udh3r?file=/src/App.js

When I use the code with the url below:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

the code works for me

but I wanna use it with this url

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos

This way I can get the list of all values

I use this code to show the information from the user/todo list

```
{user.title}
```

And it works for me

But I was not able to get the list of all values to be displayed in the app.

I try to use the code below

```
{user.map((parameter) => <p>1</p>)}
```

It says that map() is not a function.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `user` is an object, you can only use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for array.

Comment: user get the data from "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos" url. This is an json file. How can I transform this json file into an array that can I use in my app?

Comment: I've implemented an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-toolkit-saga-stoic-euler-cjhgx-forked-2hxkp?file=/src/App.js is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want. What files did you change it to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `user` as an object by doing `setUser({...data})`, [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) can only be used for array.

Since response `data` is an array, you can directly set it as `setUser(data)`

**user.js**

```
 export function* handleGetUser(action) {
      try {
        const response = yield call(requestGetUser);
        const { data } = response; //data is an Array
        console.log('data',data);
        yield put(setUser(data));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

**userSlice.js**

```
const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: "user",
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    getUser() {},
    setUser(state, action) {
      const userData = action.payload; //setting userData (Array) as data
      return { ...state, data:userData };
    }
  }
});
```

**App**

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {user.data.length}
      {user.data?.map((obj) => <h1 key = {obj.id}>{obj.id}.{obj.title}</h1>)}
    </div>
  );
```